# Copy class from child element

Tags: xslt

I am trying to copy the class from a child element to it's parent.
In the following example I am trying to move the class *hasChildrens* on to the parent *li*

```
<li class="plain" id="portaltab-about-level1">
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/hccrems/about" class="hasChildrens" title="">
        <span>About HCCREMS</span></a>
</li>
```

.

```
<xsl:template match="li/@id[contains(., 'level1')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="current()/a/@id" /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Is my value-of expression correct?

Comment: No. Your current context is an attribute (`@id`) and you are trying to get a value from an `a` element inside it. You are also trying to *create* a `class` attribute inside that attribute. This will never work with any XML.

Comment: What is your expected result here? The `li` element already has a `class` attribute - it cannot have another with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **overwrite** the existing `li/@class` value with the `@class` value of its `a` child, try:

```
<xsl:template match="li[contains(@id, 'level1')]/@class">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="../a/@class" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

or just:

```
<xsl:template match="li[contains(@id, 'level1')]/@class">
    <xsl:copy-of select="../a/@class" />
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming your stylesheet also has an *identity transform* template (or other templates to handle the other nodes).